# Days between date do not working...

Tags: php, date, between, days

Hello I wrote php code for calculate days between two dates. Can you show me where I make mistake?

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$date = "2015-03-08";
$temp = date_create($date);
$datediff = $today - $temp;
$days = floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
```

Comment: What goes wrong when you run the code?

Comment: When I set today to 2016-01-06 and second date to 2016-01-01 the output is:
datediff: 2015
days: 0

Comment: I know I tried to do the same a couple of weeks ago. I ended up doing the calculation with subtraction. $datediff = abs($date1 - $today)

Comment: Sorry but still do not work... What is the difference between 6-5 and |5-6| ?;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use phps DateTime Object:

```
$today = new DateTime(); // Passing no argument defaults to today
$newYear= new DateTime('2016-01-01');
$interval = $today->diff($newYear);
$diff = $interval->format('%a');

echo $diff;
```

Output

```
5
```

If you want to have a signed number then use this

```
$diff = $interval->format('%R%a');
```

Output

```
-5
```

So you know $newYear was 5 days **before** $today.

Comment: Ok it will probably work and how to return today in phps DateTime Object to $today variable?

Comment: Adjusted the code for you.

Comment: Ok i think it works but how to convert object data to string?

Comment: Use `$interval->format()` and any of the options explained in the manual http://php.net/manual/de/dateinterval.format.php

Comment: Works great! Please tell me the $diff is int or string or maybe object because it returns only "5" :)

Comment: $interval is object and $diff is string

Comment: Oh yes, thank for your help.